# Power series and ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

When we are dealing with finding radius of convergence for a power series , we apply the ratio test and it works . I'm curious about the case in which ratio test isn't helpful and we should use another tests . I've tried many examples but didn't get any proper result .

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample
$$
\frac 12 + \frac 13x + \frac 1{2^2}x^2 +\frac 1{3^2} x^3 + \frac 1{2^3} x^4 + \frac 1{3^3}x^5 + \cdots, 
$$
then the ratio test does not work, but the Cauchy root test could confirm.

Alternate form: $\sum_0^{+\infty} a_n x^n$, where
$$a_n =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac 1{2^{k+1}}&n = 2k, \\
\dfrac 1{3^{k+1}} & n =2k+1,
\end{cases} \quad [k \in \mathbb N]. 
$$

Comment: Can you provide the closed-form please ?

Comment: I tried to apply root test but didn't get result . Can you help please ?